# How to combine if let match expression in rust

Tags: rust, match

//here is my code. It is a Temperature Converter that takes input for Kelvin, Celsius or Fahrenheit and outputs converted value for corresponding contrary units.

// Problem:

// it will ask value first, which must be number, so the loop restarts. this is OK
// it will then ask for unit, which must be k,c or f. Upon different entry, it does catches and print "input k for kelvin, c for celcius F for Fahrenheit"
// But input doesnot register and jumps to the begening of the loop asking for value in numbers.

//All in all i want to catch the unit variable with k,c or f else ask the user to do so, not jump to the begening of loop.

// i am learning rust so excuse me for anything out of the norm.

//Here is my main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    
        println!("\nWelcome. This is Temperature-Converter\n");
        println!("I work with Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin");
        println!("\nPlease Input the Value you want to convert: ");
        
    loop{    
        let mut value = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut value).expect("Failed to read line");
        let value:f32 = match value.trim().parse(){
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("please input value in number(s).");
                continue;
            }
        };

        println!("Thank You, I have the value: {value}.\nPlease provide it's respective unit of measurement.");
        println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");
        
        
        let mut unit = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut unit).expect("Failed to read line");
        let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
        let unit = match unit.as_str() {
            "K"=>"K",
            "F"=>"F",
            "C"=>"C",
            _=>{
                println!("please input K, F or C for Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celcius respectively.");
                continue;
            }
        };
        
        println!("Thank you for your input. I see that you want to convert {value} degree {unit}.");
        println!("Please wait while i provide all possible conversions.\nThis will be quick.");
        
        
        if unit == "K"{
            let value_c = value-273.15;
            let value_f = (((value-273.15)*9.0)+(32.0*5.0))/5.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to: {value_c}C and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        }
        else if unit == "C"{
            let value_k = value+273.15;
            let value_f = (value*(9.0/5.0))+32.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to:{value_k}K and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        }
        else if unit == "F"{
            let value_k = (((value-32.0)*5.0)/9.0)+273.15;
            let value_c = ((value-32.0)*5.0)/9.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is Converted to: {value_k}K and {value_c}C");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature-Converter. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        };

    }
   

    
}
```

//i tried :

```
if let unit = match unit.as_str() {
    "K"=>"K",
    "F"=>"F",
    "C"=>"C",
    _=>{println!("please input K, F or C for Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celcius respectively.")}
};
```

// In fact i am having hard time understanding "match" and scope and return value of "loop"

Comment: Learning Rust is great, but you'll need to explain the technical problem here in more detail. Is it that you're not sure how to convert the `if` chain into a `match`?

Comment: One thing you can do is use your initial `match` into a screen as well, adding an `_ => { ...error handler... }` branch.

Comment: yes.
when i use match with variabe of String type i had to convert String type to &str type using .as_str() but when i try to use the same match expression with `if let` expression, throws error saying expected &str got String.

Comment: It's true, you can't match directly on `String`, but you can on `&str` via `as_str()`. You do this already with your unit warning code. I'm saying you can expand that instead of the `if` chain.

Comment: sorry my code is very compact and difficult to read. i will try to edit it. and keep this in mind next time.
Yes, i tried error handler and it is catching it. no issues there. it is just that after notifying error, std::io goes back from the beginning of the loop. 
I am trying to bind this match inside a loop/if let somehow so that when i exit out of it, i can target the nested loop by 'target and not start form the beginning, and also get the value out of matched statement.

sorry if this doesnot make sense.. thank you for trying

Comment: A lot of the trouble in reading the code comes from it being very dense, with a lot of stuff going on for any given line. Consider spacing things out a bit better, like `x - y` instead of `x-y`. You can also omit things like `:f32` if the type is trivially derived from the calculation, as `value` already has the right type for instance.

Comment: One way to make breaking out of a loop easer is to *use functions* so your control flow is easier to manage. You can just `return`.

Comment: Rust tends to steer towards patterns like "keep invalid states unrepresentable", that is have `enum TemperatureUnit` on to which you can add a lot of functionality. Likewise, make a `struct Temperature { unit: TemperatureUnit, value: f32 }` to represent temperatures. Break up this monolithic code into smaller, more easily tested parts. What you have here can only be tested as a giant chunk of code, you can't test that, say, a particular line works correctly. If that line was in a function it'd be trivial to `#[test]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program logic can still be simplified, for now only the syntactical problems are dealt with here:

```
fn main() {
    println!("\nWelcome. This is Temperature-Converter\n");
    println!("I work with Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin");
    println!("\nPlease Input the Value you want to convert: ");

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        let mut value = 0.0_f32;

        match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
            Ok(_) => {
                value = match input.trim().parse() {
                    Ok(num) => num,
                    Err(_) => {
                        println!("please input value in number(s).");
                        continue;
                    }
                };
                println!("Thank You, I have the value: {value}.");
            }
            Err(_) => println!("Failed to read line"),
        }

        println!("Please provide it's respective unit of measurement.");
        println!("K: for Kelvin    C: for Celsius     F: for Fahrenheit : ");

        let mut unit;
        loop {
            unit = String::new();
            match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut unit) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
                    match unit.as_str() {
                        "K" | "F" | "C" => break,
                        _ => println!("please input K, F or C for Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celcius respectively."),
                    }
                }
                Err(_) => println!("Failed to read line"),
            }
        }

        println!("Thank you for your input. I see that you want to convert {value} degree {unit}.");
        println!("Please wait while i provide all possible conversions.\nThis will be quick.");

        if unit == "K" {
            let value_c = value - 273.15;
            let value_f = (((value - 273.15) * 9.0) + (32.0 * 5.0)) / 5.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to: {value_c}C and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        } else if unit == "C" {
            let value_k = value + 273.15;
            let value_f = (value * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to:{value_k}K and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        } else if unit == "F" {
            let value_k = (((value - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0) + 273.15;
            let value_c = ((value - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is Converted to: {value_k}K and {value_c}C");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature-Converter. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
            break;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your great help. learned a lot how to get value out of match in case of integer, floating number and string. like you said, i have further made syntactical adjustment. like putting loop within let statement. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for to user: Kaplan
i have just defined variables with loop and later break the loop with variable value out of the loop.

```
fn main() {
    
        println!("\nWelcome. This is Temperature-Converter\n");
        println!("I work with Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin");
        println!("\nPlease Input the Value you want to convert: ");
        
        let value:f32 = loop{
            let mut value = String::new();
            std::io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut value)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            match value.trim().parse::<f32>(){
                Ok(num) => break num,
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("please input value in number(s).");}
            };
        };
        println!("Thank You, I have the value: {value}.\nPlease provide it's respective unit of measurement.");
        println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");
        
        let unit = loop{
            let mut unit = String::new();
            std::io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut unit)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
            match &*unit{
                "K" | "F" | "C" => break unit,
                _=>{
                    println!("Please input K, F or C for Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celsius respectively.\nI am not case sensitive.");
                }
            };
        };

        if unit == "K"{
            let value_c = value-273.15;
            let value_f = (((value-273.15)*9.0)+(32.0*5.0))/5.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to: {value_c}C and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
        }
        else if unit == "C"{
            let value_k = value+273.15;
            let value_f = (value*(9.0/5.0))+32.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is converted to:{value_k}K and {value_f}F");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature Conversior. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
        }
        else if unit == "F"{
            let value_k = (((value-32.0)*5.0)/9.0)+273.15;
            let value_c = ((value-32.0)*5.0)/9.0;
            println!("{value}{unit} is Converted to: {value_k}K and {value_c}C");
            println!("Thank You for using Temperature-Converter. It was a pleasure to assist you. Byee!!");
        };

}
```